# Read and write XML file with "!" character

Tags: xml, batch-file

this is xml file

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
```

I use this code to read and write file

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (%CONF_DIR%\process-conf.xml) do (
    echo %%a )
```

And this is result when i write a new file

```
<//www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
```

I guess "!" is special character, anybody know how to do this? I have spend so much time to do this.

Comment: How is it related to Salesforce? Seems, you have attached a wrong tag

Comment: Do you have [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) enabled? you need to disable it during expansion of the `for` variable `%%a`, otherwise any `!` are consumed by the delayed expansion feature...

Comment: Don't do it in batch. Use an XML parser. `<!` has a special meaning in `XML` - and this is just one of the many ways you can trip up on it. Outline what you're trying to accomplish, and we can give you a better solution.

Comment: @aschipfl Oh my god, it's work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable delayed expansion, when you use the for loop parameter.
If you need delayed expansion, you can toggle it.

```
setlocal DisableDelayedexpansion
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (%CONF_DIR%\process-conf.xml) do (
    set "line=%%a" -- Here the delayed expansion have to be disabled
    setlocal EnableDelayedexpansion
    rem here you can use delayed expansion again
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
)
```